# Would like to have a divider between category names where there are more than 1 to show. (and no divider when there is only 1 category name)

Tags: ee2, categories, loop

This is the site with 2 category names in the blog:

http://www.hogarthlighting.co.uk/blog/article/melba-the-savoy-hotel-london

News Picture Lights.

I would like it to show this when there are 2 or more category names

News / Picture Lights

Would I use 'if' statements? I have tried but had no success.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some variables from the Channel Categories loop to execute this.

Ref:

http://ee2docs.com/add-ons/channel/categories.html#variables

Inside of your Channel Categories loop:

```
{category_name} {if count != total_results}/{/if}
```

This places a `/` after each category name until you reach your last sequence of the loop.

**Edit** Oops, of course you have it in a `{exp:channel:entries}` loop. Here is your answer:

http://ee2docs.com/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#id149

Use the backspace param to cut off the end of your last loop. Example:

```
{categories backspace="2"}

    <a href="{path='blog'}">{category_name}</a> /

{/categories}
```

This will remove the last character of the last loop, the `/`. You might need to adjust the backspace number depending on your formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it in an entry tag. - so I don't think that will work.    {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="1" disable="member_data|pagination"}  

Category: {categories}<a href="{path="blog"}">{category_name} {if count != total_results}/{/if}</a>{/categories}
</div>
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}

Comment: @user6821 I edited my answer to give you a better answer.